# How can i download a file from another remote computer

Tags: python-3.x, remote-connection

I'm trying to download a file from target computer remotely while having reverse connection. I am using Linux as my server machine and my target machine (client) is Windows 10. My code is written in python3.9.
Before modifying my code I was able to download files, however I would lose connection as soon as entered wrong file path. So now I modified the code to first confirm if the path given exists or not. So now I'm able to keep my connection with the client alive and if I enter wrong file path it does show the error message, however the problem is that now I'm not able to download the file by proving the correct path. Now when I enter correct path nothing happens, the cursor just blinks. Can I know what's wrong in either side of my code and the correction and also how to maintain the connection incase of wrong input, as at the moment I lose connection with the client side whenever I enter something wrong.

**Here's my server side code:**

```
while True:
    #BUFFER_SIZE=1024
    # get the command from prompt
    command = input("Command >> ")
    if command == "":
         continue
    # download file  
    #THIS IS SERVER MACHINE - LINUX
    elif command.lower() == "download":
        client_socket.send(command.encode())
        print("")
        filepath = input(str("Please enter the file path: "))
        client_socket.send(filepath.encode())
        confirm = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
        if confirm == "Please enter correct File Path":
            print(confirm) #just checking if I'm getting response from client side,but it seems that I dont.
            print("")
            continue
        elif confirm == "Press [y] to Confirm Download": #add hereTOMORO
            print(confirm)
            inp_confirmation = input(str("Press [y] to Confirm Download: "))
            client_socket.send(inp_confirmation.encode())
            print("Recieving file... ")
            results = client_socket.recv(1078000)
            new_file = open(filepath, "wb")      
            new_file.write(results)
            new_file.close()
            print("")
            print(filepath, "Has been downloaded and saved")
            print("")
        else:
            Err = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode()
            print(Err)
            print("")
            continue
```

**And Here is my Client side code:**

```
while True:
if command.lower() == "download":
    file_path = s.recv(1024).decode()
    if os.path.isfile(file_path):
        msg2 = "Press [y] to Confirm Download "
        s.send(msg2.encode())
        confirmation_recv = s.recv(1024).decode()
        if recv_confirmation.lower() == "y":
            with open(file_path, "rb") as file:
                print("sending file... ")
                data = file.read(1078000)
                s.send(data)
                while(data !=""):                         
                    data = file.read(1078000)
                    s.send(data)
                    file.close()
                    print("Done Sending!")
    
    else:
        msg = "Please enter correct File Path"
        s.send(msg.encode())
```

**Thanks!**